# how to save a dictionary in python to a text file separated by white spaces

Tags: python

**Code description**

```
    mydic={node.getId():(round(x0),round(y0))}
    print mydic.items()                          
    output = open('output.txt', 'ab+')
    for key, value in mydic.items():
        output.write(str(key))
        output.write(str(value))
        output.write("\n")    
    output.close()
```

**Output-text file**

Deepu(794.0, 586.0)

Facebook(800.0, 329.0)

LinkedIn(789.0, 768.0)

Google+(502.0, 671.0)

Viber(716.0, 559.0)

GoogleTalk(1093.0, 678.0)

Plus2(1072.0, 239.0)

Btech(534.0, 253.0)

Mtech(788.0, 136.0)

**Desired Output**(how is it possible-please help)

Deepu 794 586

Facebook 800 329

LinkedIn 789 768

Google+ 502 671

Viber 716 559

GoogleTalk 1093 678

Plus2 1072 239

Btech 534 253

Mtech 788 136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `output.write()` lines in the for loop to this:

```
output.write("{0} {1} {2}\n".format(str(key), str(value[0]), str(value[1]))
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `str` calls. `format` should handle that.

Answer (score 0):

A little more pythonic with [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):
Also note the conversion to ints.

```
mydic={
    "Deepu":(794.0, 586.0),
    "Facebook":(800.0, 329.0),
    "LinkedIn":(789.0, 768.0),
    "Google+":(502.0, 671.0),
    "Viber":(716.0, 559.0),
    "GoogleTalk":(1093.0, 678.0),
    "Plus2":(1072.0, 239.0),
    "Btech":(534.0, 253.0),
    "Mtech":(788.0, 136.0)
}

from itertools import chain
print "\n".join(" ".join(chain([key],[str(int(number)) for number in value])) for key,value in mydic.items())
```

Output:

```
Viber 716 559
Google+ 502 671
Facebook 800 329
LinkedIn 789 768
Plus2 1072 239
Mtech 788 136
Btech 534 253
Deepu 794 586
GoogleTalk 1093 678
```